# Fetch API with API Keys (Twitter API)

Tags: react-native

I am a new programmer getting used to React Native. I recently started learning about Fetch API and how it works. My issue is that I cannot find examples of people using API keys to access information in their fetch statements (I struggle to articulate useful Google searches I am so new to coding).

I'll provide the simple project I am trying to build. I would like a program that queries an user's timeline for every tweet they have posted (or as far back as I can go)

Can anyone explain to me how this might work? Where do I enter my access tokens etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this [github project](https://github.com/nairobijs/react-native-tweets/tree/c4b4825eae511d83a3f4c498c319b676c0b4e947) can help you. The [README.md](https://github.com/nairobijs/react-native-tweets/blob/c4b4825eae511d83a3f4c498c319b676c0b4e947/README.md) file explains to you where to put your consumerKey and consumerSecret. Also, you should probably look at this [twitter api response example](https://gist.github.com/hrp/900964) so you know what you can get from it, and how it is formatted.